# Read MAC Iteration from pkcs#12-file in Java

Tags: java, pkcs#12

My aim is to read the MAC Iteration value in Java from a pkcs#12 file, just like `openssl` prints it out using following command in a shell:

```
/home/foo> openssl pkcs12 -info -in myPkcs12.pfx -passin pass:myPassword 
MAC Iteration 25000
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Data
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to easily read the MAC Iteration count with the `Bouncy Castle` (Bouncy Castle + Bouncy Castle Provider) library.

```
final File certFile = ...; 
final PKCS12PfxPdu pfx = new PKCS12PfxPdu(Files.readAllBytes(certFile.toPath()));
final Pfx asn1Structure = pfx.toASN1Structure();
final MacData macData = asn1Structure.getMacData();
final BigInteger iterationCount = macData.getIterationCount();
```